# What domain names are allowed? Is it possible to get a ".df" domain?

Tags: dns

I don't understand really well the domains business, but I have seen some rare domains around, for example these webpages:

- http://c9.io/
- http://repl.it/

And I want to know if it is possible to get any domain I want, lets say a .rf domain or a .kj domain.

Thanks for your help

Comment: You can't get any random domain and you can't post any random question in SO

Comment: @manojlds Well, the latter isn't exactly true...

Comment: Both `io` and `it` are country codes, as you can see from the list at IANA (see my comment below) and even if `io` is not really marketed as such. But `it` is the ISO3166 country code for Italy and `io` for British Indian Ocean Territory.

Comment: Two letters TLDs are country codes, so you can use only those in ISO3166 list with minor changes (like `uk` instead of `gb`, `eu` which is not a country per se, etc.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, it don't seem to be possible to get a .df domain. Here is a list of the possible domain extensions:
http://www.idcwebs.com/Understanding_Web_Extensions.htm
http://www.webopedia.com/quick_ref/topleveldomains/countrycodeA-E.asp

You can probably get df.someavailabledomainextension, example: df.com or df.me and then create subdomains, like mysite.df.com if that would work for you

Comment: Thanks, that's what I wanted to know

Comment: Here is the true list of current existing TLDs (this changes over time): https://www.iana.org/domains/root/db   The process to create a new one is both long and complicated, as it does not have only technical aspects of it. It is completely out of reach for an individual. But otherwise see https://www.icann.org/